# Python: remove driver for deleted shapekey

Tags: python, shape-keys

I'm trying to delete shape key drivers using Python, to clean up scenes. However, I cannot delete some drivers for previously deleted shapekeys:

```
driver_data_path = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.animation_data.drivers[0].data_path
bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.animation_data.driver_remove(driver_data_path)
```

brings up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_remove(): property "key_blocks["Key 1"].value" not found
```

What I understand is that the `data_path` is an rna path, which is changed to `key_blocks["..."].value` when the shapekey is deleted. But then it cannot be found by `driver_remove()`...

Is this a bug, or is there another way to delete drivers?

Comment: As far as I am aware, when the item with the driver is deleted then the driver will also be removed.

Comment: I thought so too, but it appears not to be the case, at least with shapekeys.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. `bpy_struct.driver_remove` should not rely on the existence of `data_path` or the removal of a `key_block` should also delete related drivers. The `data_path` attribute of the driver is not read-only by the way.